# How to instantiate and register a JobListener in the quartz.properties file?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I've read from many sources where people have said that it is possible and intended that a listener can be instantiated and registered to a scheduler all in the properties file

But I searched everywhere and can't find a single example of this.

Note: I am using this [Quartz Initiazlizer Servlet](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerServlet.html) to start my scheduler. Therefore I won't be able to use the conventional method of registering a JobListener to the scheduler. Other method of doing this is very accepted

Basically I want to do this:

```
JobListener jobListener = new SchedulerGlobalListener();
scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(jobListener);
```

In this (under quartz.properties)

```
org.quartz.jobListener.NAME.class = com.foo.MyListenerClass
org.quartz.jobListener.NAME.propName = propValue
org.quartz.jobListener.NAME.prop2Name = prop2Value
```

*
*
Below is what I've tried and the results

**#quartz.properties#**

```
org.quartz.jobListener.SchedulerGlobalListener.class = com.scheduler.SchedulerGlobalListener
```

**#listener class#**

```
public class SchedulerGlobalListener implements JobListener {

    private String name;

    public SchedulerGlobalListener() {
    }

    public SchedulerGlobalListener(String name) {
        if(name.isEmpty())
        {
            this.name = "SchedulerGlobalListener";
        }
        else
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String setName(String name) {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void jobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {
        // do something with the event
    }

    @Override
    public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException   jobException) {
        System.out.println("I just ran this job: " +   context.getJobDetail().getJobClass().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void jobExecutionVetoed(JobExecutionContext context) {
        // do something with the event
    }
    }
```

Result:

```
INFO: QuartzInitializer: Quartz Scheduler failed to initialize: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JobListener name cannot be empty.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. I totally missed this (under [Quartz config documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/)):

> For example if the properties file contains the property 'org.quartz.jobStore.myProp = 10' then after the JobStore class has been instantiated, the method 'setMyProp()' will be called on it.

**quartz.properties**

> org.quartz.jobListener.SchedulerGlobalListener.class =
>   com.scheduler.SchedulerGlobalListener
>   org.quartz.jobListener.SchedulerGlobalListener.globalListenerName =
>   SchedulerGlobalListener

**SchedulerGlobalListener.java**

```
public void setGlobalListenerName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you find how hor to use Quartz and wrtie and trigger your jobs

http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-joblistener-example/

In Quartz there is a cron expression which describes the interval of quartz job to start again here

1. http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger
2. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm 
   you found how to write cron expressions.

**Quartz simple trigger**

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("TriggerName", "group1")
    .withSchedule(
        SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
        .withIntervalInSeconds(5).repeatForever())
    .build();
```

**Quartz Cron Trigger**

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("TriggerName", "group1")
    .withSchedule(
        CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
    .build();
```

If you are using spring then all quartz properties you can mention in your context file as

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
            <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="propertName">propertyValue</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="beanName" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">  
      <property name="jobFactory">   
           <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory"/>  
       </property>
       <property name="dataSource" ref="JNDIDataSource" />  
       <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />  

       <property name="quartzProperties">    
           <util:properties location="classpath:/quartz.properties"/>  
       </property>

       <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="triggerBean"/>
            </list>
       </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: thanks for answering but this is simply not what I wanted. I've updated my question

Comment: I have Spring in my project but I'm not using it for my quartz scheduler. I'm using this to initialize the scheduler
http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerServlet.html

Comment: I didn't use quartz in this way but i update my ans with provision to intitalise factory with property file option

Answer (score 1):

You have already done things almost.

Please [refer](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigListeners) 
this link.
You just have to specify the name of the listener class in quartz.properties file 
and make sure that the specified listener class is in your classpath.

Refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-joblistener-example/)
article for how to use joblistener except the part to register the 
joblistener with scheduler. Instead, add the above mentioned properties to quartz properties file.